# What is targets in a makefile implicit commands

Tags: makefile

Can any one tell me what is targets in the below make file with some implicit rules. **I have searched in net alot, but haven't found anything helpful.** It will be pleasure if anyone explains what is targets, construction commands, dependencies, and macros in a makefile.

```
COBJECTS = menu.o users.o resellers.o propspects.o
HFILES = menu.h

leads: $(COBJECTS)
    gcc -o leads $(COBJECTS)

menu.o users.o resellers.o prospects.o: $(HFILES)
```

Comment: `make all` probably? I dont really understand your question. There are plenty of makefile resources on the internet

Comment: What "below implicit rules" do you mean? You seem to have a malformed Makefile.

Comment: I didn't get you @redFIVE, I would like to know what are all the targets in the code above. is my question wrong?

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry I have updated my question

Comment: You still seem to be missing a tab; if that's the only thing wrong, then we can explain the different parts of this makefile.

Comment: @Beta is it fine now?

Comment: Are you really saying you can't find documentation?  Why not, for example, the GNU make manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html  For example, the introduction to rules: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this rule:

```
leads: $(COBJECTS)
    gcc -o leads $(COBJECTS)
```

the target is **`leads`**, the prerequisites are **`$(COBJECTS)`**, the command is **`gcc -o leads $(COBJECTS)`**.

In this rule:

```
menu.o users.o resellers.o prospects.o: $(HFILES)
```

the targets are **`menu.o users.o resellers.o prospects.o`** and the prerequisite is **`$(HFILES)`**. It has no commands.

Answer (score 1):

The only really meaningful target defined in that makefile is `leads`. That also happens to be the default target so `make` and `make leads` will do the same thing.

There are other targets that exist as part of the rules necessary to build the `leads` target but those are all internal make defaults and not very interesting to run by hand.

Among the list of other possible targets (and among the more interesting out of the entirely uninteresting bunch) are:

- menu.o
- users.o
- resellers.o
- prospects.o